# How can we convert a octet format file to its original mime type file?

Tags: javascript, file, mime-types, octet-stream

While attempting to download a PDF/Word/RTF file from a website, I observed that the download button, upon inspection, wasn't a direct link. Upon clicking the button, the file started downloading, and an **octet-stream**(`blob:https://hiring.websiteName.com/dc7344cc-1cde-452f-8f92-a89ec666f934`) link appeared in the **chrome://downloads/** section. Subsequent attempts to download the same file resulted in the generation of random links in **chrome://downloads/**.

I'm interested in understanding how the website converts the **octet-stream** link to PDF/Word/RTF files.

Comment: When you clicked the download button JavaScript likely started downloading a binary blob from the server which would later be displayed or saved with a technique like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547475/save-to-local-file-from-blob)

Answer (score 0):

### Deriving Mime-Types is literally Magic

Here [at MDN is a nice read on Mime-Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) where they also mention some [means of deriving the mime-type from a stream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#other_methods_of_conveying_document_type).

One common way to identify the content of a file is using the so called "Magic Numbers" of "Magic Bytes". These are some of the first characters/bytes in the contents of the file.

[Here on another Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#In_files) you can read more on "Magic Numbers" in files.
[And on this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) you find a list of these file signatures.