# Can I use javascript to locally create and save a humongous file?

Tags: javascript, client-side, progressive-download

I’d like to use javascript to create and save a large .csv file client-side.  This has been asked and answered before (see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13405129/2336725), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18690450/2336725), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21012580/2336725), or [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2897619/2336725), for example), and this comes down to two approaches (among others):

1. Use [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) to implement w3c’s `saveAs()`:

   ```
   var lines = ["line 1,cell 11,cell 12\n","line 2,cell 21,cell 22\n"];
   var type = "text/csv;charset=utf-8";
   var blob = new Blob(lines,{"type":type});
   saveAs(blob,"download.csv");
   ```
2. Use `a[download]` and a data uri:

   ```
   var lines = ["line 1,cell 11,cell 12\n","line 2,cell 21,cell 22\n"];
   var type = "text/csv;charset=utf-8";
   var downloader = $('<a download href="data:'+type+','+escape(lines.join(''))+'"></a>')
       .appendTo("body")
   downloader[0].click();
   downloader.remove();
   ```

My problem is that my file can be gigantic: 18 million lines and 2.5 Gb (and I’d like to be able to handle more).  Creating `lines` uses too much memory and crashes the site.  But there’s no reason to store `lines` in the browser’s memory just to save it to the hard drive.  Is there a way to create a progressive download using javascript (in other words, start the download but keep appending lines as I calculate them)?  Or would my only option be to download the file as separate chunks that the user must then join together?

Comment: While the question is well-written and properly-structured I think that the possible answers will be too opinion based.

Comment: @Jonast92 I would agree with this being too opinion based if my question were "which of my approaches is better".  But my question is "is what I want to do at all possible", which doesn't seem to be opinion based (IMO).

Comment: I see. Perhaps the best solution is simply to _try_ both and see which is more suitable by taking a look at some benchmarks, then you'll know the answer, at least for your scenario, and you could share it with the world! :) --Although I do understand that you'd like to spare some time by waiting for an answer but you should probably not count on it.

Comment: @Jonast92 I’m not sure you’re understanding me.  I've tried both approaches.  Google Chrome reports that the tab’s memory goes to 1.5 Gb, the cpu to 135-140 (whatever that means), and the tab crashes, presumably because `lines` is too big.  Hence my desire to save the file to my hard drive without creating the entire object in javascript's memory.  Something like `blob=new Blob(); saveAs(blob); blob.append(lines);` in that order.

Comment: I recently came across https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js, which looks like it would address the issue I was having (although I've not tried it out).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTML5, you can try using the FileSytem API. See [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/toying-with-the-html5-file-system-api--net-24719) for information on the subject, and [here](http://www.noupe.com/design/html5-filesystem-api-create-files-store-locally-using-javascript-webkit.html) for a more practical example on how to create and access files fron the client-side.

Comment: I am indeed using html5.  Thanks for the links, and [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) seems to provide even more examples.  Unfortunately, though, it appears that [FileSystem has been discontinued](http://caniuse.com/#search=filesystem), and I expect that support for this approach will only decline in the future.

Comment: The FileSystem API doesn't have full support, only Chrome, Opera and some mobile browsers support it (basically, Webkit-based browsers). Since yours is a rather uncommon app, I thought this suggestion might have worked for you, and that browser support mightcome second on your list, after being able to generate these large files on the client.

Comment: The FileSystem has been discontinued but it's not likely that they are going to remove it. Too many web apps depends on it even the chrome extension use it.