# How can i read txt file line by line

Tags: javascript

I want to read txt file line by line, right now it's showing
everything that i have in my file, i want to pass each new line to variable ,how can i do it?

```
var file = "file:///C:/Users/Viktor/Desktop/test.txt";

function readTextFile(file,line) {

  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(rawFile.readyState === 4) {
      if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status === 0) {
        var allText = rawFile.responseText;

      }
    }
  };
  rawFile.send(null);
}

readTextFile(file);
```

Comment: split on the new line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string on the new lines.

```
var allText = rawFile.responseText,
    lines = allText.split(/\n/g);  //.split("\n")
console.log(lines.length);
```

Comment: Thanks! and as well is it possible to delete line from txt file?

Comment: JavaScript (in the browser) has no way of updating that file directly. You can do something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690450/how-to-generate-and-prompt-to-save-a-file-from-content-in-the-client-browser